# Render based on TemplateId

Tags: email-template, pageblocktable, rendered, pagemessages, page-template

I have a requirement to show an apex page message "XX YY" if the selected template id to email is "Update Status". (This message needs to be displayed when they make the selection not when they click the "Send" button.)

Please find my page here:

```
<apex:page standardController="Incident_abv__c" recordSetVar="Incidents" extensions="IncidentListActionController" tabStyle="Incident_abv__c">
    <apex:form >


        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Incidents to Include in Attachment" id="Pb1"> 
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!cancel}"  rendered="{!SelectedSize == 0}"/>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="inc" rendered="{!SelectedSize > 0}">
                <apex:column value="{!inc.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Rep_abv__c}"/>                
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Incident_Loaded_Date_abv__c}"/>                                
                <apex:column value="{!inc.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}"/>                
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Status_abv__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>      
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderEmailFields" action="{!ApplyTemplate}" rerender="PB2" >
            <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedTemplateId}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Email" id="PB2"  rendered="{!SelectedSize > 0}">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!send}" reRender="Pb1"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:selectList id="chooseTempalte" label="Choose Template" value="{!selectedTemplateId}" size="1" onChange="rerenderEmailFields(this.value)">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TemplateOptions}"/>

                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:InputText value="{!ToEmailAddrs}" label="To Addresses" style="width:100%"/>
                <apex:InputText value="{!CCEmailAddrs}" label="CC Addresses" style="width:100%"/>
                <apex:InputText value="{!Subject}" label="Subject" style="width:100%"/>
                <apex:InputTextArea value="{!Body}" label="Body" style="width:100%;height:300px;" />                                      
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```