# Output label not conditional

Tags: apex, selectlist, pagemessages, selectoption, page-messages

I have a requirement to show  page message for a particular selected template. The template selection done here. But render is always returning true in this case. Can someone help me here?

```
<apex:selectList id="chooseTempalte" label="Choose Template" title="Select your Template"        value="{!selectedTemplateId}" size="1" onChange="rerenderEmailFields(this.value)">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!TemplateOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:outputLabel style="color:red;"  rendered="{!IF(selectedTemplateId='Update Status - Send to ABSM', false, true)}" >  
  Please note this selected option  will set the status value to Under Review <br/><br/>
</apex:outputLabel>
```

Please find the apex **controller** snippet here.

```
public List<SelectOption> getTemplateOptions() {
        options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (EmailTemplate t : etMap.values()) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id,t.Name));
            if((selectedTemplateId == '' || selectedTemplateId == null) && t.Name == 'Update Status - Send to ABSM')
            {
                selectedTemplateId = t.Id;
                ApplyTemplate();
            }
        }

    return options;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `{!IF(selectedTemplateId='Update Status - Send to ABSM', false, true)}` is always true?

Comment: are you sure the templateId is a label and not a string? Could you include the Apex code where you're setting up the TemplateOptions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render based on TemplateId](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58588/render-based-on-templateid)

Comment: Hi Barcotter! yes the selectedtemplateid is a string which contains salesforce id of email template. I need to typecast that to ID and make like ID.Name=='Update...'.

Comment: This had several flags saying it was a duplicate of your last question, though to my mind you showed that you had done some more work since and the question had changed somewhat, so I closed the other one. In future your best bet would be to edit the first question (assuming it doesn't have several answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a record ID to `selectedTemplateId` with this:

```
selectedTemplateId = t.Id;
```

and then comparing it with a string in the page, which is why the comparison evaluates as `false` and then your `IF()` function returns `true`.

You haven't listed the code that populates `etMap` but as long as you're initialising it with a query that includes the `Name` field (or if it's coming from a trigger), then you should be able to do something like the following. I'm using a new variable (`selectedTemplate`) as I'm guessing the other is used as a page parameter.

```
public EmailTemplate selectedTemplate {get; set;}

public List<SelectOption> getTemplateOptions() {
    options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (EmailTemplate t : etMap.values()) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id,t.Name));
        if((selectedTemplateId == '' || selectedTemplateId == null) && t.Name == 'Update Status - Send to ABSM')
        {
            selectedTemplateId = t.Id;
            selectedTempalte = t;
            ApplyTemplate();
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

Then in the page you can test against the name field as you want:

```
<apex:outputLabel style="color:red;"  rendered="{!IF(selectedTemplate.Name = 'Update Status - Send to ABSM', false, true)}" >  
  Please note this selected option  will set the status value to Under Review <br/><br/>
</apex:outputLabel>
```